# I'm stuck on this epsilon - N proof. I got some way and I'm stuck on the this step

Tags: real-analysis

Using the $\epsilon-N $ definition of the limit, 

let $a_{n}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{n^{2} + 4} - n}{2}$

Show that$$\lim_{x\to\infty} a_{n} = 0$$

Working so far:

I used the fact that $(a - b) = \frac{a^{2} - b^{2}}{a + b}$ and eventually that simplifies to

$|\frac{4}{\sqrt{n^{2}+4}+n}| < 2\epsilon$

I don't know how to isolate the epsilon so that I can finish off the $\epsilon$ - N proof. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|a_n|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{n^{2} + 4} - n}{2}\right|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+4}+n}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2}+n}=\frac 1n$.
We know that $\frac 1n<\varepsilon \iff n>\frac 1\varepsilon$. Therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$ we put $N:=\left\lfloor\frac 1{\varepsilon}\right\rfloor$. If $n>N$ then $1/n<\varepsilon$ and then $|a_n|<\varepsilon$.

The most difficult element of such proofs is to find an estimate that will make our calculations easy. My tips are the following:

- Remember to find a bound from the above of $|a_n-a|$ ($a=$ limit).
- The right-hand side of $|a_n-a|<b_n$ should be simpler than l-h side.
- The right-hand side has to tend to zero.
- Try omitting parts that aren't important, that is they don't change the value of the limit (they are negligible for large $n$). Here I dropped the value $4$ since if $n$ is big the value four under the radical sign is negligible (compare value $1 000 004$ with $1 000 000$ if $n=1000$).